Code copies range from one workbook and pastes the range into another workbook fails on first try but succeeds by just hitting F5 in the debugger
I have about 130 lines of code in a Public Sub (Excel, VBA). All the actions are about the same and all our pretty small. Here are some examples:
 '   Copy Total Payout Table percentages
    Set rngTest = wksTestGames.Range("$S$4:$S$123")
    Set rng = wksGames.Range("$S$4:$S$123")
    rngTest.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '   Copy Team Payout Tables percentages
    Set rngTest = wksTestGames.Range("$V$4:$V$123")
    Set rng = wksGames.Range("$V$4:$V$123")
    rngTest.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '   Copy Not Used Payout Tables percentages
    '   LowNet-C
    Set rngTest = wksTestGames.Range("$Y$4:$Y$123")
    Set rng = wksGames.Range("$Y$4:$Y$123")
    rngTest.Copy
    '   Copy Card Matching Option
    rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Set rngTest = wksTestGames.Range("TotalGameScoreCardMatching")
    Set rng = wksGames.Range("TotalGameScoreCardMatching")
    rngTest.Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Variables that start with rng are dimensioned as Ranges. If they have Test in the name they refer to the source workbook, otherwise they are for the target workbook.
During testing the first copy-paste usually runs successfully but the second gets a 1004 error. and goes into the debugger stopped on the statement that has xlPasteValues in it. Continuing by clicking on F5 or F8 causes the statement to succeed but the next statement with xlPasteValues fails in the same way. This goes on for almost all of the 4 statement groups.
Failure did not loop when I used the error handler L_E1004. But some coding errors caused unending loops.
This seems like a timing problem, where my code gets ahead of the runtime and causes the failure.
Is there a way to take a breather, like for a millisecond, to give the runtime time to catch-up?
Am I doing something the hard way?
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Here is the error routine:
L_E1004:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then Resume

Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
Exit Sub


When you try pasting you do not need to do it in a range having the same number of rows/cells like the copied range. Setting the ranges in that way, please try rng.cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues. Or try setting Set rng = wksGames.Range("S4")...

If you only paste values you can assign values without copy e.g. rng.Value = rngTest.Value. In this case both ranges should be the same size.

Maybe reading How to avoid copy/paste also helps you to avoid the issues.

Both answers were helpful. I changed my error routine to count errors. There were only six in program that I referenced. Changing the copy paste to a variable assignment statement got rid of all the errors. I think it slowed things down a little. I have not measured. I always have the same shape range in both workbooks. How to avoid copy/paste was interesting. Thanks to everyone who responded.

As a future reference (there are instances where you really need to copy/paste) always do application.cutcopymode=False before copying and after just to make sure to clean the clipboard. On a related note, as you have noticed, if you copy/paste multiple times in succesion you start to get memory leaks. For this you need to wait to the PC to finish things with stuff like DoEvents or Sleep commands (this is not the case but start to consider it when your code works at times and not at others in the same line)

This type of repeated operation becomes cleaner if you create a sub to manage the "copy values" process:
Sub Tester()

    CopyValues wksTestGames.Range("S4:S123"), wksGames.Range("S4")
    CopyValues wksTestGames.Range("V4:V123"), wksGames.Range("V4")
    CopyValues wksTestGames.Range("Y4:Y123"), wksGames.Range("Y4")
    CopyValues wksTestGames.Range("TotalGameScoreCardMatching"), _
                  wksGames.Range("TotalGameScoreCardMatching")
 
End Sub

'copy values from `rngFrom` into same-size range with top-left cell `rngTo`
Sub CopyValues(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    With rngFrom
        rngTo.Cells(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub

